# Getting fatal error config.php line 14

Tags: php, mysql

I am making my forum!
I have sql database and everything that I need to publish to the web (domain etc.)
So after launching my forum to the web I am getting the following error when trying to open my forum:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in /storage/ssd5/357/5453357/public_html/config.php:14
>   Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd5/357/5453357/public_html/main.php(3):
>   include() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /storage/ssd5/357/5453357/public_html/config.php on line 14

I tried everything but nothing worked!
Maybe someone from here can answer my question...
How to fix this?

Comment: What PHP version? `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Default database engine is InnoDB on MariaDB 10.1

Comment: Great! Didn't answer my question, but nevermind. What PHP version are you running "on the web"?

Answer (score 1):

Try mysqli_connect() instead, ‘mysql’ is deprecated. This is the case for every mysql function, so make sure everything is updated to ‘mysqli’. Hope this helps